Prevent div from scrolling when content changes
I have two divs side-by-side: input and output.  input is contentEditable.
input's input text is modified by javascript into display: inline divs (effectively span elements) that form the content of output.
A scroll event listener on input synchronizes output's scrollTop value so that they scroll together.
All works fine except sometimes a change near the bottom of the input text causes output to scroll down, out of sync with input.
Questions

What might be causing this? **
Can automatic scrolling of a 'div' be prevented?
If not, what events can I listen for when output's content changes, so that I can re-sync output's scrollTop with that of input?

When the content of output changes, it doesn't fire a change event, an input event, or even the deprecated MutationEvent.  It is possible to listen for the scroll event but, by the time it fires, the element is already scrolling. So, when it's scrollTop is reset, there's a disconcerting jump.
A MutationObserver does observe a change when a node is added/removed or an attribute is changed.  However, my output to the output div is typically three nodes which remain in place: only their text content changes.  So I'm left trying to fudge it with, perhaps, an unobtrusive style change or empty node that is cyclically added/removed in order to 'poke' the mutation observer: a solution, but rather unsatisfactory.
** Apologies for no minimal reproducible example. I'm only idly interested in an answer to my first question: having seen this happen, I think I should watch the output div for any and all spurious scrolls regardless of why -- unless, of course, there's an answer to my second question ;)

Post code as a [mcve]. Without any code it's like asking a mechanic to fix your car over the phone.
